# Changing Domain for Office 365 Sharepoint to Custom URL

Tags: office365

Our company currently uses Office 365 E3 version.

We have been using sharepoint for sometime now however our URL is currently nameofcompany.sharepoint.com . We'd like to change it to something more custom such a sharepoint.companydomain.com .

From my research so far I can't for the life of me find any documentation by Microsoft to change this.

I'm hoping someone has come across this issue and may know the solution for this

Thanks!